# how to install pcap in ubuntu using python

Tags: python, ubuntu, pcap

this is my code :

```
import pcap ,struct

pack=pcap.pcap()
pack.setfilter('udp')
key=''
for recv_time,recv_data in pack:
   recv_len=len(recv_data)
   if recv_len == 102 and recv_data[42]== chr(02) and recv_data[101] == chr(03):
      print struct.unpack('>I',recv_data[49:53])[0]
      print '登陆了'
   elif recv_len == 55:
      print struct.unpack('>I',recv_data[49:53])[0]
      print '登陆了'
```

and i use this to install pcap :`sudo apt-get install python-libpcap` , it installed ,

but when i run the code , it show error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "weapon.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pcap ,struct
ImportError: No module named pcap
```

what can i  do ,

thanks

Answer (score 5):

For me on Ubuntu 10.04 the package is called python-libpcap:

```
sudo apt-get install python-libpcap
```

Then when I do:

```
import pcap
```

It works great!

Comment: i use `sudo apt-get install python-libpcap` but it show error too

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: i see this : "You are using Ubuntu 10.10"

Comment: Hmm, according to packages.ubuntu.com it's the same thing. Try python-pypcap instead of python-libpcap.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that you have pip installed.

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

Then you can install pypcap:

```
sudo easy_install pypcap
sudo pip install pypcap
```

I verified it for Ubuntu 14.10.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the installed module doesn't match the version of python you're running.

Look in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` and see if `pcap` is there (substituting the version you're using for 2.7).

Comment: i see it is in the /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/ , so what can i do ,

Comment: @zjm What version do you need?   If you run your script with python2.6, you should be able to import without a problem.  Are you trying to run with py3?